# How can I generate a Bernoulli random integer array in rust?

Tags: rust, random

I am trying to create a random 2D array in which each entry is 0 with probability `p` and 1 otherwise. In python, numpy makes it simple:

```py
rand_arr = (np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) < p).astype(np.dtype('uint8'))
```

In rust, I wrote something like this

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use rand::distributions::Bernoulli;
use ndarray::{Array2};

// Create a random number generator
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

// Create a Bernoulli distribution with the given probability
let bernoulli = Bernoulli::new(p).unwrap();

// Generate a 2D array of random boolean values using the Bernoulli distribution
let rand_arr: Array2<bool> = Array2::from_shape_fn((nrows, ncols), |_| {
    rng.sample(bernoulli)
});

// convert bools to 0 and 1
let rand_arr = rand_arr.mapv(|b| if b { 1 } else { 0 });
```

This is awfully slow, in fact slower than the python version! Which tells me I am doing something wrong. How can I write a faster implementation of this?

Comment: Did you compile it in release mode? Also there's definitely something missing in your code.

Comment: You probably don't have to convert your array in separate step, and can do it in `Array2::from_shape_fn`. Now you have to iterate over an entire array twice (and memcpy it, since it holds different types).

Comment: @drewtao Yes, I compiled in release mode. The code is not complete. I copied out the relevant lines from the larger python-to-rust code I am writing.

Comment: I edited it to what I think you meant. Feel free to change it if it's not accurate.

Comment: Note that "python version" is actually not executing python, but highly optimized C (or maybe even Fortran) code. So if your rust version is not as efficient (and it is not due to additional copies and memory access) there is no reason for it to be faster, or even as fast as python one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before starting, allow me to turn your code into something testable.

```rs
use ndarray::Array2;
use rand::distributions::Bernoulli;
use rand::Rng;
use std::hint::black_box;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn main() {
    let nrows = 200;
    let ncols = 400;
    let p = 0.2;
    let bernoulli = Bernoulli::new(p).unwrap();

    let (rand_arr, t) = original(bernoulli, nrows, ncols);

    println!("{t:?}");
    black_box(rand_arr);
}

fn original(bernoulli: Bernoulli, nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> (Array2<u8>, Duration) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let t = Instant::now();
    let rand_arr: Array2<bool> = Array2::from_shape_fn((nrows, ncols), |_| rng.sample(bernoulli));
    let rand_arr = rand_arr.mapv(|b| if b { 1 } else { 0 });

    (rand_arr, t.elapsed())
}
```

This reports about 302 microseconds when run in release mode on my computer. That'll be the baseline. We can now plug in different functions for `original` to time them.

Note that if you don't specify an integer type, Rust will use `i32`. I've picked `u8` to match the Python version.

---

First, I'll clean up your code without changing the meaning.

```rs
fn original_clean(bernoulli: Bernoulli, nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> (Array2<u8>, Duration) {
    let rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut iter = rng.sample_iter(bernoulli);

    let t = Instant::now();
    let rand_arr =
        Array2::from_shape_simple_fn((nrows, ncols), || if iter.next().unwrap() { 1 } else { 0 });

    (rand_arr, t.elapsed())
}
```

This uses [`sample_iter`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.sample_iter) which can be more efficient than calling `sample` multiple times. It also uses [`from_shape_simple_fn`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.from_shape_simple_fn) since you're not using the index. But most importantly, it does the mapping from booleans to integers in-place.

This one takes 237 microseconds, which is substantial, but it would be useful to know how the time is split between the array creation and the random generation.

```rs
fn not_rand(_bernoulli: Bernoulli, nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> (Array2<u8>, Duration) {
    let t = Instant::now();
    let rand_arr = Array2::from_shape_simple_fn((nrows, ncols), || 1);

    (rand_arr, t.elapsed())
}
```

This generates an array of all ones. It takes 24 microseconds. So 90% of the time is spent in random generation. I went to find out [what RNG NumPy uses](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#design).

> `default_rng` currently uses `PCG64` as the default `BitGenerator`

Let's see [what rand uses](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html).

> The current algorithm used is the ChaCha block cipher with 12 rounds.

I'm not super familiar with the performance of different RNGs, but ChaCha is a cryptographically secure RNG, so it's probably slower. There's a crate for PCG-64 in rust: [rand_pcg](https://docs.rs/rand_pcg). I made a function using that to plug into the timer.

```rs
fn pcg64(bernoulli: Bernoulli, nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> (Array2<u8>, Duration) {
    use rand::SeedableRng;
    let rng = rand_pcg::Pcg64::from_entropy();
    let mut iter = rng.sample_iter(bernoulli);

    let t = Instant::now();
    let rand_arr =
        Array2::from_shape_simple_fn((nrows, ncols), || if iter.next().unwrap() { 1 } else { 0 });

    (rand_arr, t.elapsed())
}
```

This runs in 132 microseconds! You may even be able to use a cheaper RNG (in both Rust and Python) if your use case allows.

If this is still slower than NumPy, I wouldn't be that surprised. NumPy has its performance-intensive code in C, so it isn't burdened by Python's usual slowness. However, the Rust version should beat Python if the logic outside of NumPy ever takes a substantial portion of time.

Here's all of that on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=6ebca50267903f8a3a91e64d1f8bd766), except for the PCG because the crate isn't available.

---

I went ahead and tested the Python just to check. It's not timing exactly the same thing, but it should give an idea of how the Rust version is doing.

Edit: I didn't notice that `random.rand` uses the old MT19937 RNG, so I've updated this to use PCG through `default_rng`. MT19937 is about 60% slower. I also tried Rust's [mt19937](https://docs.rs/mt19937) but it was quite slow.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

nrows = 200
ncols = 400
p = 0.2

a = time.perf_counter()
rand_arr = (np.random.default_rng().random((nrows, ncols), dtype='float32') < p).astype(np.dtype('uint8'))
b = time.perf_counter()

print((b - a) * 1000 * 1000, "microseconds")
```

This takes 370 microseconds.

Comment: Minor issue is that `np.random.rand` uses the "legacy" interface (i.e. it'll use a big old MT19937 RNG for compatibility with old code).  Using `np.random.default_rng().random()` will use the newer Generator interface which should be nearly twice as fast.  Still slower than Rust, but not as bad.

Comment: Hmm, using `default_rng` does speed up the python slightly. The performance gap between PCG and MT is much wider in rust than python. I'm guessing this is because the rust MT library isn't optimal. I'll edit the answer to use `default_rng`.

Comment: Not tried to use MT in Rust, nor looked at the source, but you might be using a 32bit generator which would need two draws per sample.  I also note that instantiating `default_rng` will cause it to be seeded from your OSs CPSRNG and you've excluded that time from your Rust timings.  That construction is maybe 50ms of work, so almost 15% of the runtime in that code.

Comment: Assuming you mean μs, yeah I didn't put much into the python one. I also couldn't find a way to generate bools or ints directly. If you have a better python version, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. This is exactly what I need as I am still learning the language. I have a question about the timing. I created a cargo project and put the code in main.rs. If I run `cargo run --release`, I get a reported time of ~550μs. If I then execute `./target/release/rusttest` I get a time of ~2ms. What am I doing wrong in the second case?

Comment: That sounds correct, so I'm not sure what would cause the timing difference. The only differences between those are environment variables, which don't matter here.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid might be due to dynamic frequency scaling being applied by your CPU/OS.  In the `cargo run` case I'd expect that a significant amount of code will be being executed and hence the core will spin up to a higher clock frequency compared to just running the executable when it doesn't consider it worth doing that.  https://github.com/cyring/CoreFreq can be useful to see what's going on if you're using Linux